# How to pivot record based on week number in mysql?

Tags: mysql, pivot

I can easily pivot the result date wise but unable to do same in week number wise.

The table structure exp.

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `products` */
insert  into `products`(`product_name`,`date`,`sales`) values 
('Micro','2020-08-01',100),
('Micro','2020-08-02',200),
('x','2020-08-02',300),
('y','2020-08-01',300),
('z','2020-08-03',400),
('x','2020-08-03',400),
('y','2020-08-10',500),
('z','2020-08-10',500),
('x','2020-08-10',500),
('y','2020-08-10',500),
('z','2020-08-10',500),
('x','2020-08-10',500),
('y','2020-08-10',500),
('z','2020-08-10',500),
('x','2020-08-11',230),
('y','2020-08-11',210),
('z','2020-08-11',240);
```

The query for showing sum of sale by date wise as below mysql code i used

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_sale;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_sale
SELECT `date`,product_name,SUM(sales) AS sales FROM 
products
WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE_ADD("2020-08-12",INTERVAL -29 DAY) AND "2020-08-12" 
GROUP BY `date`,product_name;

SELECT * FROM temp_sale;

// this code is used to get the result on date wise pivot
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN date = ''',
      DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d'),
      ''' THEN round(sales,2) end) AS `',
      
      DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
  
  FROM `temp_sale` WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE_ADD("2020-08-12",INTERVAL -29 DAY) AND "2020-08-12" ;




SET @final_query = CONCAT('select product_name,',@sql,' from temp_sale
group by product_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @final_query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

and output for the above query like as below

[image]

But the problem is that i need to sum the sum of sales record by week wise. like as

```
Product_name | sales | week-31 | week- 32 | week- 33
```

Please help here in pivot data by week number dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pivot table makes that what you want without temporary table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `products` (
>   `product_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
>   `sales` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
> ```

> ```
> /*Data for the table `products` */
> insert  into `products`(`product_name`,`date`,`sales`) values 
> ('Micro','2020-08-01',100),
> ('Micro','2020-08-02',200),
> ('x','2020-08-02',300),
> ('y','2020-08-01',300),
> ('z','2020-08-03',400),
> ('x','2020-08-03',400),
> ('y','2020-08-10',500),
> ('z','2020-08-10',500),
> ('x','2020-08-10',500),
> ('y','2020-08-10',500),
> ('z','2020-08-10',500),
> ('x','2020-08-10',500),
> ('y','2020-08-10',500),
> ('z','2020-08-10',500),
> ('x','2020-08-11',230),
> ('y','2020-08-11',210),
> ('z','2020-08-11',240);
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>     CONCAT(
>       'max(CASE WHEN date = ''',
>       DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d'),
>       ''' THEN round(sales,2) end) AS `',
>       
>       DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'
>     )
>   ) INTO @sql
>   
>   FROM `temp_sale` WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE_ADD("2020-08-12",INTERVAL -29 DAY) AND "2020-08-12" ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>     CONCAT(
>       'SUM(CASE WEEK(`date`) WHEN "',
>      WEEK(`date`),
>       '" THEN `sales` ELSE 0 END) AS `',
>       CONCAT('week-',WEEK(`date`)), '`'      
>     )
>     ORDER BY WEEK(`date`)
>   ) 
>   INTO @sql
> FROM products as p
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = CONCAT('select product_name,SUM(`sales`), ',@sql,' from products
> group by product_name');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> product_name | SUM(`sales`) | week-30 | week-31 | week-32
> :----------- | -----------: | ------: | ------: | ------:
> Micro        |          300 |     100 |     200 |       0
> x            |         1930 |       0 |     700 |    1230
> y            |         2010 |     300 |       0 |    1710
> z            |         2140 |       0 |     400 |    1740
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e336961a32d641c83fb5607a2c754547)*

Comment: if week comes in two year??

Comment: Then you need also to include the year. But you can test it with generating data